# Can I use an in-document SVG to mask a div?

Tags: css, svg, dom

I have an `<svg>` in my HTML document that I need to manipulate to make animations. Additionally, I need to use it as a `mask-image` for another `<div>`. I've always been able to use `mask-image: url("path/to/file.svg");` but the problem is that I need to manipulate the SVG for animations, so I can't just link to a static SVG file. I need to link to an SVG that's in the same DOM.

I looked into the [MDN documentation, and it appears that I can pass an element with ID selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#formal_syntax). But I cannot figure out the syntax:

```css
#outerBorder {
  border: 1px dashed #f90;
}
#logoVisual {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  mask-image: url(#logoSource);
  background: linear-gradient(#ff9900, #0099ff);
}
```

```html
<svg id="logoSource" viewbox="0, 0, 10, 10" width="50" height="50">
  <path d="M5,0L0,5L5,10L10,5Z" fill="#000000"></path>
</svg>

<div id="outerBorder">
  <div id="logoVisual"></div>
</div>
```

The mask-image isn't being applied to the iner `<div>`. Is what I'm attempting here possible at all? Or am I misreading the MDN documentation?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60877914/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not referencing an SVG in the DOM. It's creating an SVG in CSS. The reason I need it in the DOM is because I have to manipulate the SVG via JavaScript upon user interaction, and the answer you linked to doesn't let you do that.